# How to get the name from a list such as similar an input string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a list as follows

```
[<tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/conv1/weights:0' shape=(7, 7, 3, 64) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/beta:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/weights:0' shape=(1, 1, 64, 256) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/beta:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/gamma:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/weights:0' shape=(1, 1, 64, 64) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

I want to get the all name that store `BatchNorm` in the list and store in a new list without duplication. The name will be cut until the BatchNorm. For example
Input

`'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean`

Output

`'resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm'`

My expected in the new list is

```
['resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm','resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm','resnet_v1_101/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm']
```